# Can you help me backing up my identity keys? (Access denied?!)

Tags: relays

I need to wipe my Raspberry Pi and I want to keep the same identity keys tied to my relay (I guess this is the Fingerprint, right?).

I think I understand that those keys are in the /var/lib/tor folder on Linux. Is that right?

Sadly, whether I use LXTerminal or the GUI, the access to such folder is denied.

I'm using Tor 0.2.9.9... Could you please guide me backing up the files?

Thanks! :D

Comment: This is just a Linux permission error, your normal user won't have permissions to read them. You should be performing the action as root.

Comment: I tried using the sudo command but it didn't work... How do I log as root?

Comment: Can you clarify what "it" is? This really is totally unrelated to Tor, this is normal Linux usage 101.

Answer (score 1):

a fast-and-working way: open a terminal, state `sudo -s` and become a root, then run `mc` and go to the folder with your Tor install or with keys if you need just them in particular. Press F2 and "compress folder into tar.bz2" - you will have your full folder backup in a tarball one level higher =)

Comment: `sudo -i` is how you should use sudo to gain root, `sudo -s` is more dangerous since it executes the users `SHELL` environment variable as the command shell, which could be used to hijack the sudo command and escalate privileges. conversely, `-i` pulls it from `passwd`.

Comment: @canonizingironize in a possible-breakdown case I totally agree with you. But I think that the wipe is reasoned by the need of system rebuild - I have this need once a month or two when experimenting with a software.